# How to set up Tensorflow for C++ development on mac ventura 13.6

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to set up Tensorflow for my local machine, which I can use for development. This is for C++. I can't find any easy-to-install directives for TensorFlow for C++ on mac. I can't find any brew package ready-made for C++ like `brew install libtensorflow`. How is everyone building C++ tensorflow applications?

Comment: Can't Google your question? https://medium.com/@sorenlind/tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-apple-silicon-mac-with-homebrew-and-without-conda-miniforge-915b2f15425b

Comment: @273K Did you read C++? That link is for Python development. And yes I know how to use google.